# Detect when an iframe returns from a cross domain site

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain-policy

I have an iframe on my page that submits a form to a third party page.  Once that third party is done with its calculation, it redirects back to my own site.  I would like to detect when the iframe returns back to my own site.

My current approach is to use a timeout and check `location.host` of the iframe every 0.5 seconds.  However, while the iframe is still on the third party site, I get a JS error, which I would like to avoid.

Is there a good way to figure out when the iframe's location is back on my own server without getting a JS error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap your check in a `try catch` block. Alternatively you could have the page which is on your host 'call' the parent. (something like `parent.notifyReady()` ) That way you avoid having to use a `setInterval`

You could base your logic on whether to call the parent or not by using the `document.referrer` property

So on your third page you could have something like this:

```
if(document.referrer.indexOf('otherdomain.com') != -1) {
    // script called via otherdomain.com
    parent.notifyReady();
}
```

Comment: I like the alternate approach (especially if you control the code on the third page).

Comment: Wow, that's the idea I was looking for. I will test this out and let you know if it works (and will then accept this as the answer).  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 3):

```
function check() {
    try { 
        location.host; // if I error, doStuff() is never hit. 
        doStuff();
    } catch( e ) {
        setTimeout(check, 5000);
    }
}
```

Using a try / catch statement should solve this issue for you. There are likely other ways around this, however after reviewing your question this was the first that came to mind.

Another alternative is to listen for the `onload` event from the iframe. This (in chrome at least) fires each time the iframe page changes. http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/DwVJX/1/ here is a quick demo. In the iframe click on the jsFiddle logo to go back to the homepage. I understand this doesn't tell you IF you're on the right domain or not, but in conjunction with the try/catch this eliminates the need for a timer.

Comment: That was my first thought too, but I am still getting an error in my console.  At least I do in Chrome.  It doesn't stop the execution, but I would still like to avoid the error.

Comment: Can you provide a live example for us to see? http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/VWnLG/ I don't see it here. I don't even get an error on `throw "error"` in place of `error()`

Comment: Here is a quick example.  http://jsfiddle.net/4Vt83/ Just click the "Start Test" link and you will see that in Chrome you get a JS error in the console, which isn't caught by the try/catch block.  I guess, since it isn't stopping execution, you could argue that it is a "warning" rather than an error, but it certainly shows up as an error, which I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are currently doing is the only way to reliably detect whether an iframe is or isn't on a page hosted on your parent page's domain.

Most iframe properties are inaccessible (throw an exception when accessed) while the iframe is on a different domain than the parent.  An exception is actually an indication that the iframe IS NOT on your site, so simply catch the exception and try again.  If no exception is thrown, the iframe is on a page that is in the same domain as it's parent.